# I want to see the HTTP request whenever I tap a specific button on an android app. How can I do it?

Tags: android, http, http-post

I want to find out the URL that is being hit whenever I tap a button inside an app on my android smartphone. Is it possible to find this out? If yes, can you guide me the way?

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: For the sake of security, the released applications disable logging

Comment: is there any way to get the URL?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.